# Getting Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." on Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to connect to local Wifi connection on my iOS device, but whenever I am trying to execute below code it's giving exception:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://myIP/value?" + requestData).
```

Exception:

> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009
>   "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

This works fine if my Mobile Data is ON, but as soon as I turn off my mobile data and connect to my local WiFI(without internet) this error starts appearing.

**EDIT**

As per the suggestion below, I tried to find out cellular option but I think it's not available in iOS 13.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app has the permission to access the WLAN.

1.Open system setting

2.Cellular ->App using wlan&cellular

3.Find your app and check  **WLAN & Cellular Data**

Comment: Thanks. This option is not available in iOS 13

Comment: Could you share your screenshot?

Comment: I have edited my question with the requested screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: What I have observed it is if at app launch, Mobile Data is OFF, in that case, it's working fine but suppose on the launch of the App, Mobile Data is ON and I turn it OFF after the launch than HttpClient is considering that there's no internet connection and it's not changing it states even after I connect to the WiFi(without internet).

Comment: I think this because of your app request data when app launch . So when you turn off the net it will work any more even you open the net again (HttpClient will not request multi times ).

Comment: No that's not the case, when I am turning OFF the mobile data what HttpCLient assumes that there' no connectivity but in fact, I am connected to the private WiFi(without internet) and want to fetch data through the local IP but it's throwing an exception that there' no internet connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212674/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-dishant).